# Different device heights for mediaqueries

Tags: css, media-queries

Do we have any specific height for the initial display of the page in different devices. 
I want to show a header image on load of a page, on scrolling down more content appears. For fitting the image in view area for different devices with media queries, I use width as 100% but for height I have problem in understanding?

Comment: Why dont you use `height: 100%`?

Comment: But 100% height would take default image height

Comment: making a fiddle will help solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

If your width is set to 100% then your height should be set to auto. The image will be responsive and adjust to different screen resolutions without deforming.

Comment: Do i need to put the inline width and height and override them with width:100% and height:auto?  If I don't, the image is appearing only in the height of my content.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm fully understanding what your question is, exactly. My understanding is that you are trying to place an image at the top of your site that is responsive, automatically scale according to device. All you need to do is write a little CSS on your style sheet where you use your class and point it to width:100%, meaning your image will span the width of the device, and height:auto so that the image will scale to according to the image width. You do not need to set the height of your page, that is determined by the content on the page. You may consider editing post to show code

Comment: I got the solution with CSS3 background properties. But, what I still don't understand is, when we use media queries for different sizes of same image. Do we have any standard dimensions for background images?  Anyway I know that we can use CSS3 background properties to make image responsive. In short i want to know the dimension for each device.

Comment: No, I do not believe there is any standard set of dimensions for background images, per device. Best bet is to go with percentages. Also, you shouldn't have to reset your background image for every media query; that's kind of the idea behind responsive design. Less work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou both!!

I used CSS3 background image properties, instead of fighting for height. Issue resolved. :)